# Setting trigger to enable button based on presence of content in a text box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, isenabled

In my WPF application I have a part where there is a text box which gets displayed a path set by the user. I have a button next to that text box inorder to clear the text box when clicked . While the functionality of this works fine I am trying to add a style which will keep the delete button disabled by default but enabled if the textbox contains a value .

I quite don't understand what I can use inside my data trigger to distinguishly identify the text box and its value . Here is what I have tried and with this implemenataion by default the delete button is set to disabled.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Path" 
                            Width="250"
                            Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 

                            FontStyle="Italic"
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="0,0,4,4"
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>

<GeometryButton
                    Command="{Binding RemovePath}"
                    Geometry="{StaticResource {x:Static FolderDeleteIcon}}"
                    Width="30"
                    Height="30"
                    Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"
                    />
```

Here is my style that I use in my Delete Icon

```
<Style x:Key="DeleteButton" TargetType="GeometryButton">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedPath}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Would Really Appreciate some help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the `Button` if `SelectedPath` is `null` or `SelectedPath.Length == 0`:

```
<Style x:Key="DeleteButton" TargetType="dc:GeometryButton">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedPath}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedPath.Length}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```